# how to achieve purchased for inappbilling in Phonegap 2.0?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, in-app-billing

I have implemented [inappBilling](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/InAppBilling). I haven't got any error when I click on Purchase and Owned Product button. checkout is also not working. and also I want to achieve below functionality in phonegap 2.0

```
1>android.test.purchased
2>android.test.canceled 
3>android.test.refunded
4>android.test.item_unavailable
```

which is mention [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real) in Testing in-app purchases with static responses section

Comment: Do you have any errors when you click on setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cordova/phonegap plugin has been recently upgraded to the **V3** of the **In App Billing API**. I would strongly recommend to try again with the new version of the plugin which is much more stable.

https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

Comment: @ poiuytrez Any charges for test transaction for digital goods and developer account?